# How to connect Oracle through java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have installed oracle 10g and I am trying to connect it using java. But I am not able to connect it.

```
user name - system
password - oracle10g
sid - orcl
```

I am posting my code and the error log

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestConnection {

public static void main(String[] argv) {

    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "system",
                "oracle10g");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
}

}
```

error log:

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at com.gamma.TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:30)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the   connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:359)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:672)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:237)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Is the DB on the same box as Java? Is your listener running, and listening on port 1521 on your local box, and on the localhost interface (127.0.0.1) - not just on an external IP? (You can use `netstat` to check that, and/or `lsnrctl status`). Do you have a local firewall that might be blocking connections?

Comment: i have connected to oracle(using toad) using these credentials means username-system password-oracle10g ...

Comment: It isn't the credentials, it isn't getting that far; it can't connect to that host and port. Are those the same in Toad, and is everything happening on one box (i.e. same PC, if this is in Windows)?

Comment: Unrelated but: do **not** use the `SYSTEM` account to play around with. Especially do not create tables or other objects as `SYS` or `SYSTEM`. Create a regular user and use that.

Comment: @Alex yes this is wndown nd same box

Comment: Seems nothing wrong in the code, could be a problem in the connection parameters ? Try with a different oracle user/pwd.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just testing my connection